# Iterate over columns in a text file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file in the following format:

```
1,"20130219111529","90UP:34","0000","9999","356708","2"
"-2","20130219105824","0001:11","0000","","162_005",""
```

I want to compare row 1 and row 2 (In this case 1 and -2) for some purpose. To strip out all the quotes and parse this file I have the following code:

```
if os.path.exists(FileName):
    with open(FileName) as File:
        for row in csv.reader(File, delimiter= ',', skipinitialspace= True):
            print(row)
```

The following is the output:

```
['1', '20130219111529', '90UP:34', '0000', '9999', '356708', '2']
['-2', '20130219105824', '0001:11', '0000', '', '162_005', '']
```

I want to iterate through the columns. For example, iterate through '1' then '-2' and so on.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following.

```
if os.path.exists(FileName):
    with open(FileName) as File:
        lastRow = []
        # loop over the lines in the file
        for row in csv.reader(File, delimiter= ',', skipinitialspace= True):
            # saves the first row, for comparison below
            if lastRow == []:
                lastRow = row
                continue

            # loop over the columns, if all rows have the same number
            for colNum in range(len(row)):
                # compare row[colNum] and lastRow[colNum] as you wish

            # save this row, to compare with the next row in the loop
            lastRow = row
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `zip()`. It turns two iterables into one iterable of tuples, with elements coming from both lists.

```
l1 = ['1', '20130219111529', '90UP:34', '0000', '9999', '356708', '2']
l2 = ['-2', '20130219105824', '0001:11', '0000', '', '162_005', '']

for elem1, elem2 in zip(l1, l2):
    print("elem1 is {0} and elem2 is {1}.".format(elem1, elem2)
```

Answer (score 1):

just print the first element in the row:

```
for row in csv.reader(File, delimiter= ',', skipinitialspace= True):
            print(row[0])
```

EDIT

```
rows = csv.reader(File, delimiter= ',', skipinitialspace= True)
print len(rows) # how many rows were read from the file
for row in rows:
    print(row[0])
```

Comment: I did that. The output is
1
-2

I'm confused, why does it display two lists when I do print(row) and just the elements when I do row[0]?

Comment: Well csv.reader returns a list of lists containing the individual rows. So when you `print row` you are printing the entire list, but when you `print row[0]` you are printing the first element in the list `row`

Comment: That makes sense now jramirez.

Comment: I think you meant print(len(row)) and not 'rows'?

Comment: No I meant `rows` the `row` variable is only local to the for loop so if you use it before it will raise an exception.

Answer (score 1):

If (as you said in the question, though I'm not sure if you wanted this) you want to iterate through the **columns**, you can do the following:

```
if os.path.exists(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as csv_file:
        for columns in zip(*csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True)):
            print columns
```

This will output the following:

```
('1', '-2')
('20130219111529', '20130219105824')
('90UP:34', '0001:11')
('0000', '0000')
('9999', '')
('356708', '162_005')
('2', '')
```

Comment: In this approach, how can I access 1 and -2? How do I index them?

Comment: The columns variable is a tuple of two elements, so you can use columns[0] and columns[1]. The next time round the loop, those same variables will give you the data from the next column, and so on...

Comment: If I put in print(column[0]) inside the for loop it gives me the following result:

<1
20130219111529
90UP:34
0000
9999
356708
2>

My intention is to do: 

if(element == 1):
  #do something

Comment: 20130219111529 is printed below 1. 90UP:34 is printed below 20130219111529 and so on. Sorry for the formatting mistake

Comment: Please ignore my comment. Very foolish of me to have posted that.